# HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference

Tags: sql-server

This code

```
 SELECT * FROM MBR_MST WHERE MBR_JOIN_DT=MIN(MBR_JOIN_DT)
```

is showing following error:

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a 
>   HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: What you have said is true. What is your question?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to fetch the record with the minimum join date.  Here are two methods:

```
SELECT *
FROM MBR_MST
WHERE MBR_JOIN_DT = (select MIN(MBR_JOIN_DT) from MBR_MST);

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MBR_MST
ORDER BY MBR_JOIN_DT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT m.*
FROM dbo.MBR_MST m
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT min_value = MIN(MBR_JOIN_DT) 
    FROM dbo.MBR_MST 
) t
WHERE MBR_JOIN_DT = min_value

SELECT *
FROM dbo.MBR_MST m
WHERE MBR_JOIN_DT = (SELECT MIN(MBR_JOIN_DT) FROM dbo.MBR_MST)
```